# Logistic regression interpretation help.

Tags: statistics

$D$ stands for disease and $X$ for risk factor. Now, $20 \le X \le 60$. I found the formula for the regression and it was $\log \left(\dfrac{P(D|X=x)}{1-P(D|X=x)} \right) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x = -9+0.1x$
I had no problem finding the formula but had no idea when my teacher asked me what $\beta_0 = -9$ means in the context. Also then, how do you interpret $\beta_1 = 0.1$? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: To interpret $\beta_0$, try and put $x=0$. To interpret $\beta_1$ look at the difference in $\log$-odds for a person with $x=1$ vs. a person with $x=0$.